# How do you implement AdSense on a custom domain

Tags: http, adsense, ads

I have AdSense activated but it doesn't show ads on my site yet? What should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you just started using Adsense - you'll need to wait for google to complete verification process for your website: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9715?hl=en